Distinct Count Rows with filter on Same column with Multiple Rows
I'm new to DAX and still trying to get the hang of the basics!
I'm trying to get a distinct count based on whether a filter matches multiple values on the same column.
eg. based on the following dataset
PersonId     Col1
1            -1
1            10
2            -1
3            100
4            100
5            -1
5            30
6            -1
6            100

I want a distinct count where a PersonId has a row with -1 AND another row that isn't 100 for Col1.
[Edit]
There needs to be a minimum of two rows for each PersonId. One row with -1 and another which isn't 100.
So that would be PersonId 1 and PersonId 5. Total 2.
This is the Dax I've got so far and it's not giving me the correct results. Returning 4 instead of 2.
_Measure = 
    CALCULATE (
        DISTINCTCOUNT('Data'[PersonId]),
        Data[Col1] IN { -1, 10, 40, 60, 90 } 
    )


Why would personid 2 not count? It has -1 but no 100.

@davidebacci There needs to be a minimum of two rows for each PersonId.  One row with -1 and another which isn't 100.

OK, I'll update the answer now. Power BI needs you to be more explicit with your requirements for this to work.

UPDATED
Measure = 
VAR x = FILTER( ADDCOLUMNS( VALUES('Table'[PersonId]), "myCount", CALCULATE(COUNTROWS('Table'))), [myCount] >=2)

VAR a = CALCULATETABLE(VALUES('Table'[PersonId]), 'Table'[Col1] = -1, x)
VAR b=  CALCULATETABLE(VALUES('Table'[PersonId]),  'Table'[Col1] = 100, x)
VAR c = EXCEPT(a,b)
RETURN  

COUNTROWS(c)


Can you explain what's going on here with var x and how it's being used?

It is creating a virtual table of your person ids and then adding a column to calculate how many rows each has. The filter then reduces that table so each person id in there has at least 2 rows. This virtual table is then used as a filter when calculating a and b so person ids with fewer than 2 rows are excluded.
